# Vi bindings for TextMate

Tags: vim, textmate

I love both vi and TextMate. Is it possible (or even conceivable) to add vi bindings to TextMate? (Perhaps using some other key than "escape" to enter/leave the editing mode.)

Does someone know of such a possibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a plugin for vi [here](http://starvingcyclist.com/vimate).

Comment: Thanks! It is not very complete (I miss the `t/f` commands in vim), but that's a good start!

Comment: The fact the escape command is used both by vimate and for the TextMate completion is not satisfactory though. :-(

Comment: It is actually possible to change the escape behaviour of TextMate (by changing the file `TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/KeyBindings.dict`)!

Comment: noticed that the link was broken, here is the sourceforge for vimate: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tm-vi-plugin/